# How to Apply border to all the elements [on hover] of facebook's page without disrupting the entire page's look and feel

Tags: html, css, onhover

Before flagging this as already asked, pls read the whole scenario. Thanks

**SHORT VERSION :**

Just to clearly state what i am trying to achieve, here's the page https://www.facebook.com/MercedesBenzPolska/ and I want to add border to the target element (on which i am hovering), whether it be `<div>` or `<img>` or `<p>`, without the shaking

**DETAILED VERSION**

`Webpage in question`: Any of Facebook's page.

`Requirement`: Moving a cursor over an element should add border to the target element [only on hover therefore temporary border not permanent]. Permanent border will be added ONLY if I click on that element. [Simply, if I hover over an element it will be highlighted with, say, pink border and only when i click on it, a green border would be added]

`Initial problem`: adding border on elements on hover would make the whole page's structure shaky, since I am constantly adding and removing the border. For that what I did was add a transparent 1 px border to all the elements of the page, and on hover just change the color of the border from transparent to pink; thus no shaky.

`Present problem`: The above solution was working for all the pages till I encountered Facebook's page. It turns out adding the initial 1 px border totally disrupts the structure i.e. the look and feel of the page. DIVs move from somewhere to somewhere else.

How do I now solve my original problem? Is there a way of, maybe like, applying a negative margin or border, so that adding the extra 1 px border does not dirupt the page's structure? I don't know I am just suggesting. Pls help

[SCREENSHOTS]

**1. this is when the page loads [without applying the border]**

[image]

**2. Now when I hover over the div containing image ie adding 1 px border on hover, the divs move here and there**

[image]

[image]

css I am using

`* { border: 1px solid transparent !important;}` //when page loads

`.hover-selected{ border: 1px solid #e42a78 !important;}` //on hover border

`.option-selected:hover { border: 3px solid #529c56 !important;cursor: default;}` //when option is selected

The images and the css both reflect towards the same problem, the default 1px transparent border disrupts the page's css and If I don't do that, the on hover border application becomes shaky and the page's css anyway gets disrupt

Comment: Show us what you already got. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please look at guide [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @AndrzejZiółek done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px #000;

Use box shadow instead border. Box-shadow don't take up space.

```css
div {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background: red;
}

div:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px #000 inset;
}
```

```html
<div> Test </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

[`outline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline) is perfect for this. It works in a very similar way to border but does not effect layout at all.

```css
div:hover {
  outline: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Lorem ipsum sit amet.
</div>
<div>
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x100">
</div>
<div>
  Lorem ipsum sit amet.
</div>
```

Comment: Though looks like a better option, in my case, specially the facebook page, there are some divs which the outline property is not covering for some reason. Like on the link I shared, on right hand side is a div which shows `how many people like and follow this page`. On hovering, the `outline` property for some reason is not covering that div, whereas the `box-shadow` property as sggested by Germano is covering it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [box-sizing](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp) property in css. Try below code with and without box-sizing property

```
<div class="item">

</div>

.item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 50px;
  width:50px;
  background:red;
}
.item:hover{
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Problem is still there. Divs are moving and applying border gives shaky effect

Comment: try to give all * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

Answer (score 0):

I would start from something like this and move from there:

```
*:hover:last-child:before {
   display:block;
   content:"";
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   bottom:0;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   border:2px solid red !important;
}
```

Using a pseudo-element instead of putting a border on the actual object might not create as many issues with the initial layout. Still not exactly what you asked for, but I believe it's at least a bit closer. :-)

**EDIT**

I believe that the only way to achieve this as good as possible would be to be less greedy when selecting elements in the CSS, and specify a list like so:

```
a:hover:before,
img:hover:before{
   display:block !important;
   content:"" !important;
   position:absolute !important;
   top:0 !important;
   bottom:0 !important;
   left:0 !important;
   right:0 !important;
   border:2px solid red !important;
}
```

Comment: It did stop the shaking, but then like you said, only a bit closer. Like in case there's a div with a <p> in it and i am hovering over the <p>, it does not highlight the p tag but instead the div which contains it (like not even the immediate parent div)

Comment: Just to clearly state what i am trying to achieve, here's the page `https://www.facebook.com/MercedesBenzPolska/` and I want to add border to the target element (on which i am hovering), whether it be `<div>` or `<img>` or `<p>`, without the shaking

Comment: See my update! I was testing on a similar facebookpage but there's no telling what kind of CSS facebook have applied that we need to fight with to get it working "perfect". I guess the selectors need to be more specified if you want to achieve a "perfect" result. :-)

Comment: Have a look at Turnip and Germano's answer. Both did the trick and are less code too!